# How to have annotated text style to inherit from theme_set() options

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to uniformly define text style (size and family) for both plot text elements and additional annotations?

The following MWE

```
library(ggplot2) 

data1.df <- data.frame(Plant = c("Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant2", 
                                 "Plant2"), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Axis1 = c(0.2, -0.4, 0.8, -0.2, -0.7, 
                                                                                  0.1), Axis2 = c(0.5, 0.3, -0.1, -0.3, -0.1, -0.8))

theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(text=element_text(family="Palatino", size=10)))

ggplot(data1.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) +  annotate("text", x=0.4, y=0.0, label="Label", fontface="italic") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

produces

[image]

with "Label" not consistent with the theme `element_text()` definitions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If ggplot2 is loaded then this should give you the properties currently in force (if they are different than the defaults):

```
theme(text = element_text())$text[ c("family", "size") ]
```

?annotate tells us that ... "Unlike typical a geom function, the properties of the geoms are not mapped from variables of a data frame, but are instead in as vectors.". I'm assuming this to mean that `annotate` does not look in `theme()` for its font information, although that is not specifically covered by that sentence. There is also a later comment that makes me think this might be by design:  " ... but all other aesthetics are set. This means that layers created with this function will never affect the legend."

And the comment in ?annotate: "These are not scaled, so you can do (e.g.) colour = "red" to get a red point." I think the defaults for axis have a particular ratio on sizes but have not manage to find the specifics in the help files. This seems to give similar size for the annotation as for the axis titles:

```
ggplot(data1.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + 
       geom_point(size = 5) +  
       annotate("text", x=0.4, y=0.0, label="Label", 
                 family= theme_get()$text[["family"]], 
                 size= theme_get()$text[["size"]]/2.5, 
                 fontface="italic") + 
       theme(legend.position="none")
```

If you are interested in pursuing the "why" use 2.5 question you can look at ?rel and the example that uses `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(2.5)))`.

Comment: Great Thank you! A final question, I am getting an error with my code: "In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   font family not found in Windows font database" but I am not changing fonts? how do i fix this?

Comment: This question is over a year old and you are not the one who posted the question, so it's unclear how this error (from non-posted code) relates to my answer.